# Get current month in SharePoint 2013 search query

Tags: search, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to show users with birthday in current month by Content Search Web Part.
Now my main problem is how to get current month in search query. I can get {Today}, but I need get month part of today for query on user profile property with user birthday month.
How I can get this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

check this link on technet, it seems it's a similar question as yours:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c41c3991-66e3-4ef1-9309-f8d28e39aced/how-to-display-current-month-birthdays-list-using-sharepoint-2010-content-query-web-part?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: Sorry, but it's not similar. My question is about search against user profiles. And retrieving current month in search query. Question in link about query list with calculated column. It's different concepts. Thank you anyway.